# What is the correct syntax for creating a list of a list of arrays?

Tags: java, syntax

I have three lists I would like combined into one larger list. I don't know the syntax for doing this, it seems complicated.

```
List<IloNumVar[][][]> all_through = new ArrayList<IloNumVar[][][]>(Arrays.asList(through_lane1, through_lane2, through_lane3, through_lane4, through_lane5, through_lane6, through_lane7, through_lane8));
List<IloNumVar[][][]> all_left = new ArrayList<IloNumVar[][][]>(Arrays.asList(left_lane2, left_lane4, left_lane6, left_lane8));
List<IloNumVar[][][]> all_right = new ArrayList<IloNumVar[][][]>(Arrays.asList(right_lane1, right_lane3, right_lane5, right_lane7));
List<List<IloNumVar[][][]>> all_movements = new ArrayList<ArrayList<IloNumVar[][][]>>(Arrays.asList(all_through, all_left, all_right));
```

I'm getting a syntax error on the last line, all_movements. What is the correct syntax for creating this list?

Comment: Some advices: Let type interference do its job and do not define the generic types on constructor calls explicitly (`... new ArrayList<IloNumVar[][][]>...` -> `... = new ArrayList<>...`) --- variables in java should be writte in `camelCase` instead of `snake_case` (`all_through` -> `allThrough`)

Comment: The correct generic type should be `new ArrayList<List<...` in your last line instead of `new ArrayList<ArrayList<...` because the three variables you're trying to add into it are `List` variables, not `ArrayList` variables. Would be easier just to use the diamond operator `<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this.

```
List<List<IloNumVar[][][]>> all_movements = new ArrayList<>();
all_movements.add(all_through);
all_movements.add(all_left);
all_movements.add(all_right);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in the last line

all_through, all_left, all_right are List<IloNumVar[][][]> data type and your are trying to initialize them as they are ArrayList<IloNumVar[][][]>. Even if that seems logical it's not syntactically correct.
Just change that in last line of code
Here is correct code snippet:

```
List<List<IloNumVar[][][]>> all_movements = new ArrayList<List<IloNumVar[][][]>>(Arrays.asList(all_through, all_left, all_right));
```